# Can apache2 work without conf files?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

So happend that apache2 conf files contain env vars with passwords and other valuable data. 
After apache2 was started i deleted my conf files.
I know that for reboot i will have to create these files again.

How long apache2 will continue its work as expected(showing my sites)?
Does apache2 read conf files after it was started?

Im asking because so happend that i didnt restart servers but they show apache ubuntu default page

**ps -aux | grep apache**

```
www-data 27019  0.0  0.0 424372 12780 ?        S    15:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 27963  0.0  0.0 424372 12800 ?        S    16:46   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 27964  0.0  0.0 423968 12500 ?        S    16:46   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28159  0.0  0.0 423968 12424 ?        S    16:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28607  0.0  0.0 423968 11044 ?        S    17:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu   28688  0.0  0.0  12948   956 pts/0    R+   17:23   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
root     28766  0.0  0.2 423888 34928 ?        Ss    2018  06:14 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

UPD:
i know that this is bad way to delete conf files.

Comment: Just so I understand, you're asking how to stop the default apache/ubuntu page coming up when you start the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @djsmiley2k has said, Apache will continue operating without config files if the config files existed when it was started. And no, this is not a good solution, as he has said and you are aware.

That said, in answer to whether apache2 will **work** or not... I would say "**no**".

Most systems automatically restart Apache and/or reload Apache configs for various reasons. For example, it's typically for Apache to be restarted when its log files are rotated. Many of these automated tasks are necessary for the proper operation of an Apache-based web server. You would have to automate the re-creation of the config files as well... meaning you'll have to store the passwords somewhere else, at which point you've defeated the purpose of deleting the config files.

Additionally, there are unplanned restarts... such as when apache2 crashes. Stable as it is, Apache is not bulletproof. The S.O.P. is to have some method in place to watch the Apache process and restart it automatically if it hangs or crashes. Many modern systems use systemd for this. Again, you can add automate reconstruction of the config files to the restart process... but doing so still defeats the purpose of deleting the config files to begin with.

**The real solution here is to secure your sensitive data.** Environment variables should be set by whatever tool you are using to manage the Apache process. Systemd (for example) [provides](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) [tools](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#edit%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) for this. Passwords used for [local authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) should be encrypted and stored in files only readable/writable by the user that Apache is run by (ie `root`) and especially not the one it reads files as (ie `www-data`).

If you have passwords used for remote authentication (ie authentication from your webserver to another server or service... such as a database) then you should consider replacing them with pre-shared public/private keys such as used for ssh authentication... not to mention encryption between remote servers (seriously, ssh tunnels, good stuff)... again, stored in files accessible only by the privileged user that starts Apache. And, honestly, Apache itself shouldn't be handling the task of authentication to another service...

Answer (score 3):

You *can* delete the files once apache is started, and it'll continue to run until it needs to read the files again (for example if you restarted the daemon).

This appears to be a [X->Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/168762) problem, and you've not actually stated your problem, just asked a question about what you may believe to be a solution. It's not an advisable solution however.

Comment: Added more details about issue

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with not storing critical data directly inside the apache conf files here is a different idea.  Definitely, not passwords of any kind.

You can make your own *.conf file(s) inside the conf.d folder.
Apache will still load them.

Then migrate all the valuable data to a new .conf file. Now you only have 1 file to delete and re-establish.

Thus apache would still have some configuration data available, and not start as a blank apache install.  Obviously the documentRoot folder is the most important.